# how to add insert into a data component via post request in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, post

I have this data.js file in which I wrote some information:

```
    export const data = [
  {
    id: '1',
    title: 'first item',
    description: `my first item`,
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    title: 'Second item',
    description: `my second item`,
  },
];
```

And I would like to fetch or post data into this when a user submits these attributes, any idea how can this be done in react native?

Comment: So you want to store data from a database into `data` by making a fetch request or post the data in `data` to a database?

Comment: The example you are showing this is just a way to store the data locally in JSON file and then read in an array and use it for making CRUD for the learning purpose only. For a real world application you have to make http request to read and write data using some API points.

Comment: Yes actually it is for learning purposes only, there is no db but only the data.js file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first read up on REST or RESTful APIs before moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `async storage` [package](https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage) if you are storing the data locally on the user's device.